# What open source library can I use to allow users to leave messages on my site?

Tags: open-source

I have a web site already, but I would like the user to interact with me. So, I would like to let the user login and leave some messages on my site, also I would like to manage their comments. Are there any open source libraries that will help me do this?

Comment: What is a server-side scripting language of your current website?

Comment: PHP+MySQL. Linux Server.

Comment: It's not necessary to be a server-side solution, right? You can approach this with an entirely client-side solution, based on JavaScript.

Comment: Well, I think a server-side solution is better, because I can get full control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using PHP then the following libraries might interest you

http://www.awesomephp.com/?Commentary

http://sourceforge.net/projects/php-com-sys/

http://www.commentics.org/download.php

Answer (score 1):

It sound like you need something really simple to setup.

You can try using [DISQUS](http://disqus.com/)